# Forever and node.js, stopping one forever process stops all processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

So I have a few node servers running, for example in `var/www/mysite/` then in `var/www/mybackend`, also in `var/www/someotherapp`.

If I `cd var/www/someotherapp` then run `forever stop server.js` all node servers are killed, I think this applies to the other commands as well?

This is just a hassle, how do I mange multiple node apps better?

Comment: how can we tell what's messed up with your code if it's not shown?

Comment: Do all  your apps have a server.js?

Comment: why do you have to run stop? i simple exit out of the server process i want to end...

Comment: Yup, @jfriend00, dandavis, sometimes I do that to debug, I may need to run npm start to see the logs

Comment: @jfriend00 okay well that link pretty much answers my question, shall I delete this?

Comment: @dandavis - because when you're using `forever`, if the server process stops, `forever` will just start it again so you have to tell `forever` top `stop` doing that.

Comment: You don't have to delete it.  It's marked a duplicate so it's resolved.

Comment: @jfriend00: weird, i use forever and have not had a problem with _kill_ or [ctrl]+[c]. it is nice to hear of the option, and i'm not sure that i've been using it correctly, but it seems to do the job...